# Should I use "gives" or "give" in the following statement?

Tags: word-usage

> The results gives us the operating frequency and range.

Answer (score 0):

With singular subjects, we use the singular forms of verbs. With plural subjects, you use the plural forms of verbs. Is the subject of this sentence *the results* plural? It certainly is. Thus, you must use the plural form of the verb *to give* which would be *give*. *Gives* is the third-person singular form of *give*. That form only works for third-person singular subjects. Subjects of that category include the pronouns *he*, *she*, *it*, *one* and any singular noun or phrase that represents something singular. So, long story short, it should be *give*:

> The results **give** us the operating frequency and range.